# How to specify an alias in AD "Log On to" as computer name?

Tags: samba, active-directory, smb

I'm trying to setup one user tied on a Windows 10 Pro computer (kiosk) on a Samba 4.18.2-Debian powered AD domain using the `Users and Groups` > `(user)` > `Properties` > `Account` > `Log On to` functionality.

It works as expected for Windows login and I can access a Samba shares too (on another server than the DC, but also 4.18.2-Debian) using `\\official-and-long-hostname-of-the-smb-server`.

`\\official-and-long-hostname-of-the-smb-server` not being a nice name, in practice, everyone uses `\\fs`, which is an alias. The alias works usually well, except here for the kiosk where the computer refuses to connect:

```
C:\Users\kiosk>net use \\fs\temp
System error 2240 has occurred.

The user is not allowed to log on from this workstation.
```

I tried to adding `official-and-long-hostname-of-the-smb-server` **and** `fs` to the `Log On to` list but I'm still getting the same error.

I'm not sure where is the connection denied? The client that refuses to connect? Or is it the server that refuses the connection? And on what grounds? What can I do?

```
[global]
        workgroup = FOO
        realm = INT.EXAMPLE.NET
        security = ADS

        idmap config *:backend = tdb
        idmap config *:range = 700001-800000
        idmap config FOO:backend = rid
        idmap config FOO:range = 10000-700000

        idmap cache time = 1
        idmap negative cache time = 1
        winbind separator = +
        winbind cache time = 1
        winbind use default domain = yes
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes

        min protocol = SMB2

        vfs objects = acl_xattr recycle crossrename full_audit
        map acl inherit = Yes
        template homedir = /mnt/smbdata/homes/%U

        printcap name = /dev/null
        load printers = no
        disable spoolss = yes
        printing = bsd

        veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/.Trashes/.TemporaryItems/Thumbs.db/lost+found/.AppleDouble/.bin/.AppleDesktop/Network Trash Folder/
        delete veto files = yes

        recycle:touch = yes
        recycle:keeptree = yes
        recycle:versions = yes
        recycle:directory_mode = 0770

        full_audit:prefix = %u@%m(%I):%S
        full_audit:failure = connect
        full_audit:success = mkdirat pread pwrite renameat unlinkat create_file
        full_audit:facility = local5
        full_audit:priority = notice

        # Personal home auto creation. Does nothing if placed directly under [homes] for an unknown reason.
        root preexec = bash -c 'mkdir -p -m 0700 "/mnt/smbdata/homes/%U" && chown "%U":"Domain Users" "/mnt/smbdata/homes/%U"'
        
## A lot of other share definitions
        
[Temp]
        path = /mnt/smbdata/shares/temp/
        root preexec = bash -c 'mkdir -p -m 0770 "/mnt/smbdata/shares/temp/%U" && chown "%U":"Domain Users" "/mnt/smbdata/shares/temp/%U"'
        read list = @SMBShare_temp_RO
        write list = @SMBShare_temp_RW
        valid users = @SMBShare_temp_RO, @SMBShare_temp_RW
        invalid users = @SMBShare_temp_blocked
        create mask = 0664
        force create mode = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
        force directory mode = 0775
```

[image: Log On To settings]

Comment: Have you tried specifying the user you want to connect as, since the user your attempting to use, isn’t able to access the share. Post the Samba configuration file.

Comment: The user IS able to connect to the shares if we use the \\official-and-long-hostname-of-the-smb-server, or if I do not use the dsa.msc "Log On to" functionality on that account.
If I use the "Log On to" functionality AND try to connect using the short name \\fs, it is denied, even with "fs" AND "official-and-long-hostname-of-the-smb-server" listed as allowed computers to logon.

Comment: Your question says when you tried that it didn’t work.  Still fall back to asking for the Samba configuration. 2240 is “If you need to log on from this workstation, have your network administrator change the logon workstation(s) listed in your account.”, post your logon list for us

Comment: Initial post edited with requested elements